# Webpack Jest Custom Resolver

Tags: webpack, jestjs

I have a custom webpack resolver and it is used in an inline fashion

```js
import abc from 'xyz!abc
```

Where xyz is the custom resolver. This works well for running the app however when it comes to jest I'm not sure how I can use the resolver. I have no options when it comes to the resolver must be inline and cannot be mocked.

Webpack imports the resolver in webpack.config.js

```js
  config.resolveLoader = {
    modules: [
      'node_modules',
      'loaders'
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jest's [resolver](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#resolver-string) option to recreate your custom webpack resolver

> This option allows the use of a custom resolver. This resolver must be a node module that exports a function expecting a string as the first argument.
>   The function should either return a path to the module that should be resolved or throw an error if the module can't be found.

Another option is to use jest's [module mapper](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-react-native#modulenamemapper) functionality, to map imports such as `xyz!abc` to a specific file.

```
{
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "^xyz!abc$": "<rootDir>/RelativeImageStub.js",
    "module_name_(.*)": "<rootDir>/substituted_module_$1.js"
  }
}
```

the second options shows you how to map dynamically with parameters.